# Django login url

Tags: django

How to enable redirect user after login at personal page included `user.id`, like http://mysite/client/12. I added app `client`.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'client'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),    
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def user_profile(request,user_id):
    user_id = request.user.id
    return render(request, 'client/profile.html')
```

And changed in settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'client:user_profile request.user.id'
```

Now when I click LogIn I get error

```
Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'client'
```

I think that I am not trying to solve this problem correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` should be a URL, e.g. `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'`

Check the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)

Because you're doing `'client:user_profile request.user.id'` it looks like the system is trying to determine `client` as a protocol like `http` or `https`.

Comment: Ok, but /accounts/profile/ is static URL, how mak it variables?

Comment: @lepiloff if it's a login redirect then the view can pick up the authenticated user based on their session & it doesn't need variables. It just needs to get the user from the request.

Comment: Hmm, but then as it turns out on many sites in the URL there is eg user nickname??

Comment: @lepiloff yes but that's not how that setting works in django, so you could have a `profile_redirect` view which then becomes your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and in there you could do `HttpResponseRedirect('/%s/' % nickname)` to end up in your dynamic URL.